# Community or 10Gen .NET MongoDB driver?

Tags: .net, mongodb, mono, nosql

I'm studying MongoDb and I will be putting a test app. together on my Linux workstation using Mono (I'm a C# hack).  I have found this [video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/using-MongoDB-on-Mono) which discusses the official 10Gen driver in which the presenter mentions that the official driver does not support async but the communitiy driver does.  So my question is, which driver should I choose and why? (secondary question, which is the leading community .NET driver?)

Comment: try both and pick one that feels better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use the official C# driver. It is being actively developed and has the full support of 10gen. Take a look at the activity on github for the various drivers and you can get a sense of the amount of work being done on each driver.

There are plans for eventual support of an async API in the C# driver but it is relatively low priority and we don't know when we might start working on an async API.